# How to create materialize value with the source?

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I am trying to create the materialize value, when I create a source as the following:

```
case class Info(value: String)
val source: Source[String, Future[Info]] = Source.single("Start")
```

But it does not work. How to create a source with materialize value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you use `mapMaterializedValue`?

```
val source: Source[String, Future[Info]] = Source.single("Start")
  .mapMaterializedValue(_ => Future(Info("abc")))
```